# Change SVG size?

Tags: html, css, formatting

I need help with my transformicon I got from [here][1].

It stays locked to a certain size even after doing things like "width:..px", etc. How would I resize this?

You can test it out at [my site][2], just log in using the username/password 22/22.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide html and css codes?

Comment: Check out falconsnest.cf. My CSS and HTML is pretty cluttered.

Comment: Please take a tour of the help center and see how to ask a good question. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add width:100% for the image class, it will fit automatically the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Given below is `img-resonsive` style from twitter bootstrap which should make your image responsive to screen size. Additionally, you may use media queries for computer screen and set some different max-width for larger display.

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```